# Express serving static files vs AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-api-gateway, aws-fargate

are there any benefits to running a static website via S3/CloudFront vs running one via Express (via Fargate) sitting behind API Gateway? In terms of performance or any other considerations? The latter approach allowing api endpoints to also be hosted via Express/API Gateway on the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

1. Scaling in case of Cloudfront/S3 is better.
2. Caching and serving from edge locations in Cloudfront S3.
3. Cloudfront gives you options to alter req and response, say you want to add CSP headers to all response going out from your domain or say you want to prevent open redirect from you domain URL, you can use origin request and origin response lambdas in cloudfront.

Comment: thanks, but if Express is behind API Gateway (with edge endpoints or regional endpoints with custom cloudfront), is there any practical differences?

Comment: What when DDOS attack happen, what extra you will need to scale express based solution.?what is cost associated with maintaing express compared to S3 ? Encryption at rest?